# Displaying different unicode values for same character in php

Tags: php, unicode, utf-8, special-characters, utf

I am using a function to determine the unicode value in decimal for different Bengali characters.The function is :

```
               function uniord($u) {
                    $k = mb_convert_encoding($u, 'UCS-2LE', 'UTF-8');
                    $k1 = ord(substr($k, 0, 1));
                    $k2 = ord(substr($k, 1, 1));
                    return $k2 * 256 + $k1;
                }
```

It works for all the Bengali characters except `ড়` which unicode value 09DC in hex and 2524 in decimal.This works perfect when I take this character from console/textarea field.such as:

```
                $data = $_POST['data'];
                echo uniord($data);
```

But is display different unicode value when use this character from a variable .such as:

```
                $data_one = 'ড়';
                echo uniord($data_one);
```

this provide unicode value of 09A1 in hex or 2465 in decimal which is a another similar word but not my desire character value.

How to solve this. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[U+09DC](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/09dc/index.htm) has a canonical decomposition as U+09A1 U+09BC. It sounds like your text editor is saving text using [decomposed normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence#Normal_forms). See if you can change the settings to be able to save using the composed normal form, or try using a different text editor.

Or use escape codes: `"\xe0\xa7\x9c"`